# How should I find probable reason for crash 'CFArrayGetCount EXC_BAD_ACCESS (KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS)' inside pdfkit

Tags: swift, pdfkit, xcode14

I'm facing below crash but tried same steps as user did but unable to reproduce this crash. It would be grate if I get help in understanding reason of below crash.

- I have tried with simple flow as user did.
- Enable voice over did same steps. (Voice over why? Because all crash logs that we found in firebase has UIAccessibility related traces so I that it would be from one of accessibility flow but no luck.) It would be grate if you suggest what else I need to try out.

Basically what we are doing here is that fetching imaging and converting into pdf and create pdf view and dumping in PDFView using apple provided PDFKIT

Thanks!

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  CoreFoundation                 0x7c59c CFArrayGetCount + 8
1  CorePDF                        0x28c1c CGPDFTaggedNodeEnumerateChildren + 52
2  CorePDF                        0x28b70 CGPDFTaggedNodeGetBounds + 244
3  PDFKit                         0x6400 (Missing UUID 4dedb563f2df3dceae5066d6b4718b9f)
4  UIAccessibility                0x818e0 ___axuiElementForNotificationData_block_invoke + 56
5  UIAccessibility                0x5e370 __79-[NSObject(AXPrivCategory) _accessibilityFindAnyAXDescendant:byAddingElements:]_block_invoke + 84
6  UIAccessibility                0x5e4b4 -[NSObject(AXPrivCategory) _accessibilityFindAXDescendants:byAddingElements:] + 232
7  UIAccessibility                0x5e290 -[NSObject(AXPrivCategory) _accessibilityFindAnyAXDescendant:byAddingElements:] + 236
8  UIAccessibility                0x5e990 -[NSObject(AXPrivCategory) _accessibilityFindDescendant:] + 208
9  UIAccessibility                0x81748 _axuiElementForNotificationData + 356
10 UIAccessibility                0x82094 _massageAssociatedElementBeforePost + 80
11 UIAccessibility                0x83470 _UIAXBroadcastMainThread + 640
12 UIAccessibility                0x84abc ___UIAccessibilityBroadcastNotificationFunction_block_invoke + 372
13 libdispatch.dylib              0x24b4 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
14 libdispatch.dylib              0x3fdc _dispatch_client_callout + 20
15 libdispatch.dylib              0x127f4 _dispatch_main_queue_drain + 928
16 libdispatch.dylib              0x12444 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 44
17 CoreFoundation                 0x9a6d8 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 16
18 CoreFoundation                 0x7c03c __CFRunLoopRun + 2036
19 CoreFoundation                 0x80ec0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 612
20 GraphicsServices               0x1368 GSEventRunModal + 164
21 UIKitCore                      0x3a186c -[UIApplication _run] + 888
22 UIKitCore                      0x3a14d0 UIApplicationMain + 340
23 *********                      0x5dd4 main + 59 (main.m:59)
24 ???                            0x1b3306960 (Missing)
```

- Probable root cause of this crash
- What I need to try out to find or fix this crash

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Actually I just want to understand crash here and about code to understand I don't know where do this crash exactly occurred so its very difficult share code.